# Checking occurence of the word 'rain' in a json response using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to find out the occurrence of the word rain in the following JSON response and I have written the following python code and also attached the JSON response and the error I am getting in the console.

I want to check the value of `'main'` and `'description'` in `'weather'` to check if it contains the string or sub string `'rain'` so it should print `'1'` for `'Rain'`, `'rain'`, `'heavy rain'` and `'Heavy rain'`.

I wish to get the output as `1` if `rain` is present in the JSON response else `0`

```
import requests, json

r = requests.get("climate api link") 

r= json.loads(r.text)
r['weather']
def search(values, searchFor):
    for k in values:
        for v in values[k]:
            if searchFor in v:
                return k
    return None



search(r, 'Rain')
```

The JSON response:

```
{
   "coord":{
      "lon":72,
      "lat":19
   },
   "weather":[
      {
         "id":800,
         "main":"Clear",
         "description":"clear sky",
         "icon":"01n"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{
      "temp":300.255,
      "pressure":1025.08,
      "humidity":95,
      "temp_min":300.255,
      "temp_max":300.255,
      "sea_level":1025.12,
      "grnd_level":1025.08
   },
   "wind":{
      "speed":4.66,
      "deg":334.002
   },
   "clouds":{
      "all":0
   },
   "dt":1520266101,
   "sys":{
      "message":0.0043,
      "country":"IN",
      "sunrise":1520213280,
      "sunset":1520255940
   },
   "id":6619349,
   "name":"Breach Candy, Mumbai",
   "cod":200
}
```

here's the error I'm getting

```
  File "<ipython-input-3-a5896a25aff8>", line 16, in <module>
    search(r, 'Rain') #prints firstName
  File "<ipython-input-3-a5896a25aff8>", line 9, in search
    for v in values[k]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: The `'id'` key references a integer, 1520266101, and you can't iterate over that integer.

Comment: It's not clear to me where you expect `'rain'` to be found. In a key, in a string value? Can you please include a JSON response example for which your program should produce `1`?

Comment: Your code currently also returns just the `k` value, so a key in the outermost dictionary, not `0` or `1`

Comment: i just need the output to be 1 if 'rain' is present in the above JSON response. I'm new to python.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by JSON response example. Could you elaborate? because i have already provided a json response im getting in the question

Comment: by output 1 i mean print '1'

Comment: You provided a JSON example without any `'rain'` in it. That's not a very good example, because it is unclear what you are searching for. You could be looking for keys  (`{"rain": ...}`, for substrings of keys (`{"rainfall": ...}`), for strings in values: (`{"precipitation": "rain"}`), substrings in values `{"precipitation": "Heavy rain"}`), or for all of the above. If looking for substrings, what should happen when it is part of a word, like `restraint`?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I want to check the value of  'main' and 'description' in 'weather' to check if it contains the string or sub string 'rain' so it should print '1' for 'Rain' ,'rain','heavy rain' and 'Heavy rain' ...i doubt there will be a condition like the word 'restraint' because it only returns weather

Comment: Please update your question to include that information.

Comment: Did the changes. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for specific keys only, then don't try to iterate over everything else. You passed in the whole dictionary, not just the `r['weather']` list.

You also need to lowercase the value, if both `rain` and `Rain` should count.

Next, I'd return a boolean value, that's the standard answer for a 'yes' or 'no' question. When *printing*, feel free to convert that value to `'1'` or `'0'`:

```
def weather_search(response, keyword):
    """Searches the weather main and description fields for given keyword"""
    keyword = keyword.lower()
    for entry in response['weather']:
        for key in ('main', 'description'):
            if keyword in entry.get(key, '').lower():
                return True

    # nothing found
    return False

# printing 1 or 0
print('1' if weather_search(r, 'rain') else '0')
```